# EXAMPLE of Rails 4 RESTful API with Devise for Android client XML?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

I am wandering if it's possible to use gems like devise, oauth, paperclip, commentable with a Rails RESTful API?
I am building a prototype API for an Android CLient which will be sending POST and GET messages in XML? As it is a prototype I want to get it done using gems and as fast as possible! Any help\demo app\resources is Greatly appreciated!
PS: I watched ryan bates's screencasts on API's.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use OAuth, as it is meant for APIs. Will use tokens instead of cookies!